# <dialog> with JQueryUI draggable

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

So I have an issue where I want to combine the [<dialog>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) with JqueryUI [draggable](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/).

The issue comes from the fact that the  has `margin: auto` that makes it be nice and centered, and I want to have that (starting) position.

**Issues with margin:**

- The main dialog does not respond to dragging as you would expect due to it having basically width and height 100%
- I also want to make it draggable with containment in the body, but due to the above margins this means I cannot move it

I can fix the issues above by doing `margin: 0` but this breaks the positioning of the dialog and it starts from 0, 0.

**Has anyone tried to combine these two before in a way that keeps the wanted starting positioning and the expected draggability?**

### Draggable with margin auto

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script>

function drag() {
    $("#showcase").draggable();
}

</script>


<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('showcase').showModal();drag();">Click me</button>

<dialog id="showcase">
hello world
<button type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('showcase').close();">Close</button>
</dialog>
```

### Draggable with margin 0

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script>

function drag() {
    $("#showcase").draggable();
}

</script>


<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('showcase').showModal();drag();">Click me</button>

<dialog id="showcase" style="margin:0;">
hello world
<button type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('showcase').close();">Close</button>
</dialog>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so we can see the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: _"The main dialog does not respond to dragging as you would expect"_ - can you please clarify what you mean here? Apart from the different starting position, both snippets above appear to behave quite identical? (Testing in a current Chromium-based browser on Mac.)

Comment: @CBroe with the default margin the element does not follow mouse 1-to-1 but only moves about half the distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Centering the modal using the "usual" technique of positioning at top/left 50%, and then offsetting by the element dimensions using `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` did almost work - but that always makes the element jump a little bit, so that it is centered regarding the mouse cursor position.

I think your best bet is probably to calculate the proper coordinates to position the dialog absolute, with fixed pixel values:

```js
$('#trigger').on('click', function() {
   let $showcase = $('#showcase');
   $showcase.css({
      margin: 0,
      position: 'absolute',
      top: window.innerHeight / 2 - $showcase.height() / 2,
      left: window.innerWidth / 2 - $showcase.width() / 2,
   });
   $showcase[0].showModal();
   $("#showcase").draggable();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="trigger">Click me</button>

<dialog id="showcase">
hello world
<button type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('showcase').close();">Close</button>
</dialog>
```

Comment: Hmm, did not want to try to calculate the position as it's always too difficult to get the position perfectly. But thanks for reminding me that I can do CSS via JQuery too so I can only do it manually when I have draggable dialog and leave it on auto for without